# how to update the values in config file

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have an `Config.yml` file i want to update the values like below by using shell script.

current file data

```
servers: 
- uri: http://localhost:5550/service/mgmt/current
- displayName: server1
- username: user
- password: welcome
- domains:
--- default
--- domain1
- useBulkApi: true
```

Required output should be like below:

```
servers: 
- uri: https://hostname1:5550/service/mgmt/current
- displayName: instance1
- username: xx
- password: xx
- domains:
--- default
--- domain1
- useBulkApi: true
```

hostname, user, password and domain name will changes for each URI. These values are coming from script. I have to update at lease 3 server details and each server has different URI, hostname, user, password and domain.

Comment: Can you give me give me one example..

Comment: uri and display name etc those are constant,, But values remains changes  for example i need to update two server details so there two uri, display name etc.. That means i need append another server details under servers:

Comment: where these value will come from ?

Comment: These values come from my script like uri1 = http://host:5550/service.... and uri2 = http://host2:5550/service.... i need to iterate the function based on number of values

Comment: please post the actual content of script in your original question

Comment: Please read my original post, My requirement is to update/append the server details in to the file if i have more than one server.. that means i need to configure multiple server detains. thanks for your reply..

Comment: You'd better show example with 3 servers because it is hard to understand how do you choice between servers which data you need to change

Comment: servers:
uri: https://hostname1:5550/service/mgmt/current - displayName: instance1 - username: xx - password: xx- domains: --- default--- domain1- useBulkApi: true
uri: https://Hostname2:5550/service/mgmt/current - displayName: instance1 - username: xx - password: xx- domains: --- default--- domain1- useBulkApi: true
uri: https://hostname3:5550/service/mgmt/current - displayName: instance1 - username: xx - password: xx- domains: --- default--- domain1- useBulkApi: true

Comment: in original file just given one example.. My requirement is to add no of servers in the file. I hope u understand now..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to make changes to your required config files.
PS: Mention the correct path in place of `config.yml` and include more replace strings wherever you want to modify anything.
NOTE: `sed -i` will permanently replace the strings. Do validate once before modifying.

```
find  Config.yml -type f -exec sed -i 's/user/<NewUser>/g; s/welcome/<newPassword>/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your YAML document looks something like this:

```yaml
servers:
  - uri: http://localhost:5550/service/mgmt/current
    displayName: server1
    username: user
    password: welcome
    domains:
      - default: domain1
    useBulkApi: true
```

... because what you are showing does not make much sense.

The task, the way I'm going to define it (as it was very vaguely explained in the question) is to replace the values of the keys `displayName`, `username`, and `password` for the element whose `uri` value is `http://localhost:5550/service/mgmt/current` (or any particular value).  I'm ignoring the fact that the URL in the question seems to gain an `s`, making it an HTTPS URL rather than a HTTP URL, and I'm base64-encoding the password, just to show how that may be done.

To do this, we'll use `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ in a script that expects to read lines consisting of the tab-separated fields URL, display name, user name, and password.  The script uses the URL to locate and update the correct entry in the `servers` array in the YAML document. The file `Config.yml` is edited in-place.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

pathname=Config.yml

tab=$(printf '\t')

while IFS=$tab read -r uri name user password
do
        yq -y --in-place \
                --arg uri "$uri" \
                --arg name "$name" \
                --arg user "$user" \
                --arg password "$password" '
                ( .servers[] | select(.uri == $uri) ) |=
                (
                        .displayName = $name |
                        .username = $user |
                        .password = ($password|@base64)
                )' "$pathname"
done
```

Test running:

```bsh
$ cat Config.yml
servers:
  - uri: http://localhost:5550/service/mgmt/current
    displayName: server1
    username: user
    password: welcome
    domains:
      - default: domain1
    useBulkApi: true
```

```bsh
$ cat input
http://localhost:5550/service/mgmt/current      instance1       Theodore Y.     my*special password
```

```bsh
$ sh script <input
```

```bsh
$ cat Config.yml
servers:
  - uri: http://localhost:5550/service/mgmt/current
    displayName: instance1
    username: Theodore Y.
    password: bXkqc3BlY2lhbCBwYXNzd29yZA==
    domains:
      - default: domain1
    useBulkApi: true
```